# Reduce JavaFX RAM usage

Tags: java, performance, javafx, ram

I have a java program that shows 4 `LineCharts` on real time. Each of these has 2 series (I use `XYChart.Series<Number, Number>()` as `LineChart.Series<Number, Number>()` shows a warning) and the user can navigate through the X axis (Horizontal) using a slider.

My problem is that I need to keep in these series around 10000 (at peak) values for each series so the usar can go left or right (using the slider) on the charts, which in total makes around 80000 values.

(The series store up to 10000 values but the charts show 500 values at the same time, so the user can select which 500 of the 10000 he/she wants to see moving the slider)

I simply have too many values on the lists, which causes this:

[image: Object RAM usage 1]
[image: Object RAM usage 2]

As you can see in the images, most of the created objects are related to the charts, I can't really say much more, because I don't know. Is there any way to prevent JavaFX from creating this objects?

The overall RAM and CPU usage looks like this: (Which makes me believe I am creating excesive objects and making the GC work too much)

[image]

I have been searching for information, and I think `WeakReferenceQueue$ListEntry` is a node that is marked to be removed? But I am not sure about this, or how to prevent creating these.

**How can I prevent JavaFX from creating so many objects? (Nodes?)**

**These charts are just examples taken right now with around 4000 values per series, the CPU and RAM usage go even higher when using more data (up to 10000).**

Comment: [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/index.html) can render to JavaFX, but works with the JavaFX canvas rather than nodes.  Perhaps (and I don't really know), it might be a more efficient library to use for your use case.

Comment: I'll take a look at JFreeChart, it's a library that I already knew about and have used in the past, but I didn't even consider it for this case, mainly because I didn't remember it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you have created your 8 `XYChart.Series` and in each of them added all 10000 `XYChart.Data<X,Y>` values. The `Series` object stores all `Data` values in an `ObservableList`. JavaFX observability internally uses weak reference, so I assume that there is a weak reference being generated for each of the `Data` objects. Basically `Series` and `Data` are heavy and should not be used as a backing store of original data.

Given that you only display 500 values per `Series` at a time, what you can do is keep only those 500 `Data` objects in the `Series` that the user is currently viewing. Based on scroll position add new `Data` and delete old `Data` in the `Series` from a backing array containing original data points.

I have done something similar in my [project](https://github.com/AeroZealous/GroundStation/) on plotting continuous sensor telemetry data.
The README shows application images.
Particularly of your interest are lines [that update the LineChart](https://github.com/AeroZealous/GroundStation/blob/475a723075c72fb4d04438c0f76b5b5e6f58f9a4/src/ground/station/SensorPlotter.java#L103) and its [caller](https://github.com/AeroZealous/GroundStation/blob/475a723075c72fb4d04438c0f76b5b5e6f58f9a4/src/ground/station/GroundStation.java#L50).